# ESRI ArcGIS 100.9 .NET Wpf Point icon with Line Icon

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

Using ArcGIS Esri 100.9 with .NET Wpf, I am trying to combine a point icon and a line geometry, but I am not sure how to do that. I want to have a line with the point symbol at the start point and only the start point. Is there any way to do that without creating separate graphics? I am using either a `PictureMarkerSymbol` or a `MultilayerPointSymbol` for the point icon, and a `PolyLine` for the line's geometry. Is there any way I can combine the two for a graphic? I tried using a `CompositeSymbol` with `PictureMarkerSymbol` and `SimpleLineSymbol`, but that created a line with the point symbol at each vertex.

```
PictureMarkerSymbol pointSym = GenerateSymbol(iconInfo);   // custom generation function
Geometry geo = new PolyLine(iconInfo.Points);

Symbol sym = // generate the appropriate symbol for the graphic
Graphic g = new Graphic(geo, sym);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the runtime is able to render symbols like that, at this point there's not an API for creating them programmatically (it's on the roadmap to add though). However if you use ArcGIS Pro, it can be used to author this type of symbology and then be consumed by Runtime by exporting the symbol styles and using it in your runtime application.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option within the scope of my project at this time. I have just accepted that the feature does not exist and created separate icons. I hope to take advantage of the feature in the API when it is added. Thank you.

Comment: The symbols are in the end just shared as JSON. The underlying format isn't really documented, but if you do reverse-engineer it, you can use Symbol.FromJson(...) to create these symbols.